# Dividing monthly rate between Start and End Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have Monthly rate for each employee in one table which I need to distribute equally based on the Employee Start and End date in the particular project.
For e.g. The monthly rate for employee X is $4300 which is stored in Table A. The employee start & end date in the project is '2017-11-03' & '2017-12-12' respectively and is stored in Table B. I need the employee cost for both Nov and Dec months.

Appreciate any help on this.

---

Edits:

Table 1:Employee Details
Col1-Employee name
Col2-Start date
Col3- End date

Table 2: Rate Card
Col1-Location
Col2-Grade
Col3- Cost Per Month

Table 3: Employee Billing
Col1-Year
Col2-Month
Col3- Employee
Col4- Cost per month

So if Employee worked from 4-Nov-17 to 31-Dec-17 and Cost per month is $4000, then in Billing table there should be 2 entries like:

2017,Nov,Emp1,(4000/30)*((30-4)+1)
2017,Dec,Emp1,4000

I was ale to insert 2 entries in table 3 based on input from table 1 but not able to calculate the customized cost

```
case 
       when (webResource_Details_ESS_recurrent_entries.recurrent_month<>DATEPART(mm, l.start_date) or
      webResource_Details_ESS_recurrent_entries.recurrent_month<>DATEPART(mm, l.end_date))
      then
       l.Employee_Cost

       when DATEPART(day, l.start_date) <> 1 and Eomonth(l.start_date) = Eomonth(l.end_date)  then 
        (Datediff(day, l.start_date, l.end_date) *
            (l.Employee_Cost / Datediff(day,Eomonth(l.start_date), Dateadd(month,1, Eomonth(l.start_date))) ) ) 
       when  DATEPART(day, l.start_date) <> 1 and Eomonth(l.start_date) <> Eomonth(l.end_date)  then ( Datediff(day, l.start_date, Eomonth(l.start_date)) * 
            ( l.Employee_Cost /Datediff(day, Eomonth(l.start_date), Dateadd(month, 1,Eomonth(l.start_date))) ) )
            when DATEPART(day, l.end_date) <> (DATEPART(day, DATEADD(second,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,l.end_date)+1,0)))) and Eomonth(l.start_date) <> Eomonth(l.end_date) then (Datediff(day, ( Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0,l.end_date),0) ),l.end_date)
            *(l.Employee_Cost /Datediff(day, Eomonth(l.end_date),Dateadd(month, 1, Eomonth(l.end_date)))))

      end as Employee_Cost
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take the `startdate` and get the end of the month (if the end date is not the same month), get the number of days. Take the `enddate` and get the beginning of the month (if the start date is before the `enddate` month), get the number of days. Calculate each month, `(rate\#days in month) * calculated days`.

Comment: Added the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT em.employeed, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Eomonth(startdate) = Eomonth(enddate) 
         THEN   (Datediff(day, startdate, enddate) *
                (rate / Datediff(day,Eomonth(startdate), Dateadd(month,1, Eomonth(startdate))) ) ) 
         ELSE   ( ( Datediff(day, startdate, Eomonth(startdate)) * 
                ( rate /Datediff(day, Eomonth(startdate), Dateadd(month, 1,Eomonth(startdate))) ) ) + 
                (Datediff(day, ( Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0,enddate),0) ),enddate)
                *(rate /Datediff(day, Eomonth(enddate),Dateadd(month, 1, Eomonth(enddate)))))) 
       END AS wage 
FROM   employeemaster em 
INNER JOIN employeerate AS er 
ON ( em.employeed = er.employeed )
```

First Case will handle case when both start date and end date are in same month

```
eomonth(startdate) = eomonth(enddate) then (datediff(day,startdate,enddate)*(rate/datediff(day, eomonth(startdate), dateadd(month, 1, eomonth(startdate)))))
```

This calculate days and rate for month of start date

```
datediff(day,startdate,eomonth(startdate)) * (rate/datediff(day, eomonth(startdate), dateadd(month, 1, eomonth(startdate)))))
```

This calculate days and rate for month of end date

```
(datediff(day,(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, enddate), 0)),enddate)* rate/datediff(day, eomonth(enddate), dateadd(month, 1, eomonth(enddate))))
```

Comment: OP wants cost broken out by month.

Comment: The rate is a monthly rate, not a daily rate. So you are calculating a monthly rate * each day. I'd like that paycheck! :-)

Comment: `eomonth(sysdatetime())` should be `eomonth(startdate)`, this could be run the following month or whenever.

Comment: @WEI_DBA thanx for pointing it out !!! I have not done proper testing but it will give him direction to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160732/discussion-between-blindsniper-and-wei-dba).

Comment: This works great @BlindSniper when I need cumulative cost for the whole period, Recently edited the question. Need separate cost of each month involved in Start and End Date

Comment: It is already included take a look at else part simply divide it in 2 columns and you will have your monthly wages

Comment: Thanks. I did. Really helped.Appreciate your help!!